# Sitecore XP Mongo DB Configuration Issue

Tags: mongodb, sitecore

I installed newer version of Sitecore (Sitecore Experience Platform 8.1 rev. 151207 (8.1 Update-1)) and also installed Mongo DB(3.0.2) and both of them installed successfully. However I don't see any new databases created in MongoDB by Sitecore. I verified the connectionstrings.config and it has the correct path to Mongo DB(Example: mongodb://localhost:27017/analytics).

Since this is my local environment I am reusing the license of Sitecore 7.2 which also includes license for DMS.  After digging through the log file I noticed this:

8944 20:39:58 INFO xDB is disabled.
8944 20:39:58 INFO Tracking is enabled.

After doing some research I didn't find Analytics.Enabled setting in Sitecore Analytics.config file or even in /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx file. Even after updating the config file with Analytics.Enabled = true it still says "XDB is Disabled".

Is there any setting that needs to be updated? Does the license file need to be updated separately for XP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to generate a new license for Sitecore 8.1, the older Sitecore license are not compatible:

> Sitecore 8.1 now requires a license with the “Sitecore.xDB.base” key
>   to enable all features of the Experience Platform. If your license
>   file does not contain this key, Sitecore will default to Experience
>   Management (CMS-only) mode. Any customers or partners with a license
>   to Experience Platform should contact their account manager or login
>   to SPN if they are missing this key.

From the [Sitecore download page](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/Sitecore_81/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_81_Update1.aspx).

You can generate a new license by [logging into SPN](http://spn.sitecore.net/default.aspx) and you need to make sure it is "xDB enabled"

Comment: Jammmy.. Thanks for the note. I'll contact sitecore today regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

In Sitecore 8.1, You have a new config file "Sitecore.Xdb.config" where you can enable/disable CMS Only mode, Make sure that the following setting is enabled in it:

**Xdb.Enabled**

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/xdb_configuration/cmsonly_mode_configuration

Also, If you don't have a valid xDB license, CMS-Only mode is enabled by default.

Comment: Ahmed.. Thanks for the note. Value of Xdb.Enabled is set to true. However as per the above note I have been reusing the same license from 7 which might have caused the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some digging from the above notes I found that we need to update the Sitecore license. After procuring a new license Sitecore was successfully able to create databases in Mongo.